# can i do some judge to set the dir prefix in different os platform?

Tags: gradle

Cause:
the settings.gradle is like this:

```
include(':xxx')
project(':xxx').projectDir = file('./admin')
include(':xxx')
project(':xxx').projectDir = file('./core')
include(':xxx')
project(':xxx').projectDir = file('./gateway')
```

it`s works in Mac os. but when in Windows . the path is "/admin". so gradle does not work!

My Question:
can i do some judge to set the dir prefix in different os platform?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now, i  solve my question by this way:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
def SPL = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)? "/" : "./"
```

it`s seem not good!